# SSH into VM Azure

Tags: turtlebot, rosnode, ros-hydro, bashrc, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Is there a way to run ROS between two machines but not on the same network ?
Basically i want to access my nodes in a Virtual Machine created on Azure.

For future work, i'll run a node there that receives an image from my node here to process and send me the result. Is that possible ? And how can i do that ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193721/ssh-into-vm-azure/) by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run nodes anywhere as long as you setup the networking adequately to be able to connect bidirectionally. Both must be able to reach the other by name. Guidelines for setting up the network: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2014-10-06**:
The problem is that i cant ping the machine. I think it is because of Azure firewall but i did not find the solution yet. Any suggestions ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-06**:
You should find a forum for Azure users, there's not many Azure users on in the ROS forums.

**Comment by [Jaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/21435/jaro/) on 2015-01-21**:
Hi, I am facing the same problem. Did you solve the issue? Can you give me some suggestion how to do that? Thank you.